# append elements until - using while with dynamic added elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, while-loop

I have function that add to div container div's

```
 $.ajax(
    {
        type: "GET",
        url: "/LoadedData",
        data: { "pageNumber": pageNumber },
        success: function (result) {
            $('.Container').append(result);
        }
    }
```

and I want to execute that function until this div container contains div with is xxx

I try to do this with while loop but is looks like when i do :

```
while($('.Container div').is('#xxx'))
{}
```

function not see new div's appended to Container :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your code in a function that is recursively called in the `callback:` if the `result` did not match your selector.

It will continue to run until the selector is matched.

```
var container = $('.Container');  // cached the .Container element

function add_to_container() {

   $.ajax(
    {
        type: "GET",
        url: "/LoadedData",
        data: { "pageNumber": pageNumber },
        success: function (result) {
            container.append(result);
            if( !$(result).is("#xxx") ) {  // if the result was not the one...
                add_to_container();       // ...recursively call the function
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @netmajor: What type of performance? If you mean the overall time that it takes to get the proper `#xxx` result, then yes the requests are sent consecutively and therefore it will take the most time. You could send a bunch of requests, but there's no guarantee that they'll come back in the same order. Or you could have your server send batches of results, search through the results, append them if `#xxx` isn't found, or append the ones up through `#xxx` if it is found. I'd say that a `while` loop is definitely not the right approach though.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery has the each function to iterate over dom elements.

```
$('.Container div').each(function(){});
```